# How can produce an “Universal installer” in Linux?

Tags: linux, packaging, distributions

I have a source code and I want to produce an installer for all OS's (Windows, Linux) for non-confirmed users (Simple App user).
My app is in C programming Language.
I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga).
I want to resolve for them all program packages dependencies and provdide a user interface for program setup.

Comment: What interface does your program have? Is it a web app, or does it have a GUI or a command  line?

Comment: It is a command line program.

Comment: Please also make a RPM, so that that RPM can be stashed in a repository, and installed via the simple `yum install fooapp` command.

Comment: Ok for the redhat solution. But like this i need another process for Windows platform !! But I want a universal packaging solution. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to U&L. We would appreciate you reading **and applying** [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), especially the part about no chit-chat (like advance-announcement of appreciation, thanks).

Comment: Some others proposition please ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least not easily.

Windows has its own "shell" - and it uses "batch" files, which are distinct from bash.

Windows uses `.exe` files, while Linux uses `.elf`.

These make it hard to install your software. There are some solutions - you could use some cross-platform tools, like Java, that will check what OS it's running on and apply certain scripts - but that requires you to install Java if it's not there, and we fall back again to the installation issue...
You could also use web browser to tell you what OS it runs on(if you're installing from webpage); the easiest way - and most sane too, imho - is to ask user for OS/give him proper package, depending on his OS. It's hard enough to properly package program meant to be run throughout the Linux distributions.

Comment: I want to produce a .bin file to linux users and .exe file for Windows users. I think that cross-platform installer is a good choice. Can you suggest to me the best open source tool.

Comment: What exactly should this tool do?

Comment: Install the ame hieachical folder as mine in the user machine with the rigth permission files. But i want to give the user a friendly UI to select the folder he want to install the tools, set the license .. etc

Comment: @MarwenBkh And why don't you do separate installation wizards for Windows and Linux?

Comment: Because i want to automate package generating for the 2 platform and don't want to do the same thing for Windows and Linux.

Comment: Then I'd argue that it's impossible to provide it in a reasonable manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29396/discussion-between-marwen-bkh-and-matthewrock).